# Getting lagged values of indep. variables to model contemporaneous values of the dep. variable

Tags: regression, forecasting, prediction, predictor

I am trying to forecast the variable, `oenb_dependent`:

My current sample data looks like that:

```
> dput(datSel)
structure(list(oenb_dependent = c(1.0227039, -5.0683144, 0.6657713, 
3.3161374, -2.1586704, -0.7833623, -0.2203209, 2.416144, -1.7625406, 
-0.1565037, -7.9803936, 9.4594715, -4.8104584, 8.4827107, -6.1895262, 
1.4288595, 1.4896459, -0.4198522, -5.1583964, 5.2502294, 1.0567102, 
-1.0923342, -1.5852298, 0.6061936, -0.3752335, 2.5008664, -1.3999729, 
2.2802166, -2.1468756, -1.4890328, -0.79254376, 3.21804705, -0.94407886, 
-0.27802316, -0.20753079, -1.12610048, 2.0883735, -0.7424854, 
0.44203729, -1.48905938, 1.39644424, -3.8917377, 11.25665848, 
-9.22884035, 3.26856762, -0.00179541, -2.39664325, 4.00455574, 
-5.60891295, 4.6556348, -4.40536951, 6.64234497, -7.34787319, 
7.56303006, -8.23083674, 4.43247855, 1.31090412), carReg = c(0.73435946, 
0.24001161, 16.90532537, -14.60281976, 6.47603166, -8.35815849, 
3.55576685, 7.10705794, -4.6955223, 10.9623709, 5.5801857, -6.4499936, 
-9.46196502, 9.36289122, -8.52630424, 5.45070994, -4.5346405, 
-2.26716538, 2.56870398, 0.013737, 5.7750101, -27.1060826, 1.08977179, 
4.94934712, 17.55391859, -13.91160577, 10.38981128, -11.81349246, 
-0.0831467, 2.79748237, 1.84865463, -1.98736934, -6.24191695, 
13.33602659, -3.86527871, 0.78720993, 4.73360651, -4.1674034, 
9.37426802, -5.90660464, -0.4915792, -5.84811629, 9.67648643, 
-6.96872719, -7.6535767, 0.24847595, 0.18685263, -2.28766949, 
1.1544631, -3.87636933, -2.4731545, 4.33876671, 1.08836339, 5.64525271, 
1.90743854, -3.94709355, -0.84611324), cpi = c(1.16, -3.26, 0.22, 
-3.51, 0.84, -2.81, -0.34, -4.57, -0.12, -3.95, -1.37, -2.73, 
0.35, -5.38, -4.43, -3.08, 0.74, -3.03, -1.09, -2, 0.35, -1.52, 
1.28, 0.2, -0.25, -4.55, -2.49, -4.24, -0.31, -2.96, -2.24, -0.46, 
-0.06, -2.67, -1.27, -1.4, -0.7, -0.96, -2.18, -2.53, -0.52, 
-1.74, -2.18, -1.4, -0.34, -0.09, -1.65, -1.15, -0.17, -2.01, 
-1.38, -1.24, 0.09, -2.44, -1.92, -2.61, -0.34), primConstTot = c(-0.33334, 
-0.93333, -0.16667, -0.33333, -0.16667, -0.86666, -0.3, -0.4, 
-0.26667, -1.56667, -0.73333, 0.1, -0.23333, -0.26667, -1.5774, 
-0.19284, 0.38568, -2.42423, -0.93663, 0.08265, -0.63361, 0.0551, 
-0.49587, 2.39668, -1.70798, -3.36085, -2.56196, 0.16529, 0, 
-1.84572, -1.3774, -0.49586, -1.70798, -1.90081, -0.55096, -0.77134, 
-0.16529, -0.30303, -0.17066, -0.23853, -0.64401, -1.52657, -1.57426, 
-0.28623, -0.54861, -1.07336, -0.71558, 0.02385, -0.38164, -1.09721, 
0, 0.14311, -0.38164, -1.02566, -0.42934, -0.35779, -0.4532), 
    resProp.Dwell = c(0.8, -4, -3.2, 2.7, -1.6, -1, -2.4, -0.4, 
    -0.8, 1, -12.1, 0.2, -5.2, 3.7, -2.7, -1.7, 1.5, 0.7, -7.9, 
    0.3, 0.3, 1.4, -3.3, -1, -1.6, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1, -2.2, -3.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, -0.9, -0.4, -3.4, 0.9, 0.1, -0.2, -2.8, -0.8, -6.2, 
    11.3, -4.6, 1, 1.1, -1.7, 4.1, -5, 2.3, -2.3, 4.6, -6.3, 
    6.3, -6.9, 0, 2.4), cbre.office.primeYield = c(0, 0, 0.15, 
    0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 
    0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0, -0.15, -0.85, -1, 
    -0.85, -0.75, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cbre.retail.capitalValue = c(-1882.35294, 
    230.76923, -230.76923, -226.41509, -670.78117, -436.13707, 
    -222.22223, 0, -205.91233, -202.16847, 0, -393.5065, -403.91909, 
    -186.30647, -539.81107, -748.11463, -764.70588, -311.47541, 
    -301.42782, -627.09677, -480, 720, 782.6087, 645.96273, 251.42857, 
    1386.66667, -533.33334, -533.33333, -533.33333, 0, 0, -1024.56141, 
    -192.10526, 0, -730, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -834.28571, 0, -1450.93168, 
    0, 0, 0, -700.78261, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1452, 0, 0)), .Names = c("oenb_dependent", 
"carReg", "cpi", "primConstTot", "resProp.Dwell", "cbre.office.primeYield", 
"cbre.retail.capitalValue"), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = "data.frame")
```

To forecast a dependent variable, works best, if I have lagged values of independent variables.(Many thx to the user Richard Hardy, who brought me on this idea!) So,

$$y_t=X_{t−k}β+ε_t$$

In this model, lagged values of $X_t$ are used to model contemporaneous values of $y_t$. Hence, given such a model, "predictions" of $y_t$ are available k periods ahead: $\hat y_{t+h}=X_{t-k+h} \beta$, and $X_{t-k+h}$ is available (as of time $t$) for all $k⩽h$.

Any suggestion, how to find such dependent variable. Which statistical methods are suitable for this problem?

I really would appreciate examples!

Answer (score 1):

From the subject-matter perspective, you should look for leading indicators. Is there a variable/indicator (economic or financial, or whatever) that reacts first to shocks that only later affect the variable you intend to forecast? That is, is there a variable that moves first, and subsequently you see a corresponding move in the variable to be forecast? If there is, use it as an independent variable.

From the statistical perspective, you may look at cross-correlations between different variables and the variable you are going to forecast to see which ones are leading the one of interest. Finding high cross-correlations at lags other than zero is your goal (of course, you are interested in the cases where the other variables lead the one of interest, and not the other way around). You may use functions `ccf` (applied on two variables) and `acf` (applied on a vector-valued variable) in R.

Comment: Thx! From which package is `ccf` and `acf`? Would you be so kind to show an example on my data set?`I appreciate your reply!!!

Comment: You do not need to load any extra packages for `acf` and `ccf` functions, they are included in the base version of R.